# How do I add support for PIC12LF1822 to gputils

Tags: pic, assembly

I've used the PIC assembler and tool kit from gputils with success before, but I noticed that they're lacking support for my new pic12lf1822 chips. How do I go about getting it supported?

After checking out their source code I couldn't find any useful information other than lots of existing .inc and .lkr files which seems to be taken from MPASM. As I don't have a Windows box I can't download MPASM and use their files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't wait for that device to be added to gputils, and you don't want to use Windows, you could download the beta MPLAB X which runs under Linux and Mac OS. I just checked and it does support the 12F1822, so you could download it and extract the files you need. Or, use MPLAB X for your development, instead of gputils.

Comment: I can add support to gputils is someone could shed some light on how to do it. But if not I'll have to use MPLAB X for now, I have it set up and running at home. I would like to use gputils+pk2cmd though as it's free, available and I haven't gotten the PICkit to work with MPLAB.

Comment: Actually, MPLABX's assembler doesn't support my device. It has a linker file for it, but no .INC file. I guess I'll have to write it myself. :(

Comment: There is a P12F1822.INC MPLAB X include file! LF devices use the standard include files.

Comment: Where? find /opt/microchip -name P12F1822.INC returns zero hits for me. Which version and OS are you using? I'm at alpha 4 on Linux.

Comment: When I downloaded it on OSX I got beta 5 which has support for the chip, yay.